# Using Link (NextJS) make React-Dnd can't drag&drop

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-dnd

I use react-dnd to drag and drop rows in a table (tanstack-table). I use Link to navigate to that page, but when I navigate to it, I cannot drag&drop. I checked, react-dnd uses redux and when using Link tag redux-devtool doesn't work. When using a tag it works but I don't want it.

```
 <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend} debugMode={true}>
            <SessionProvider session={session}>
                <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                    <LoadingProvider>
                        <MyContextProvider>
                            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
                        </MyContextProvider>
                    </LoadingProvider>
                </QueryClientProvider>
            </SessionProvider>
        </DndProvider>
```

Something affected react-dnd's redux store and made it impossible to drag and drop

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution, maybe redux and nextJS should not be used. I changed to dnd-kit library and it worked. https://dndkit.com/